Issue with running fastchat with a model saved on a local path
I'm trying to run a model on a server using fastChat. For that I have three docker images: server, control and worker.
I'm having issues with the worker image, namely - I'm trying to run it with a model that is saved locally on the server.
The model I'm using is in hf format (safetensors), but is not on huggingface.
I'm trying to change the --model-path in the entrypoint line in the docker-compose.yaml file (from "--model-path", "${FASTCHAT_WORKER_MODEL_PATH:-meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B}") to the local path (on the server).
Here are examples how I gave the --model-path input:
a. "/<path>/<to>/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--<model>--<model-name>}"
b. "{FASTCHAT_WORKER_MODEL_NAMES:-/<path>/<to>/.cache/huggingface/hub/models--<model>--<model-name>}"
then when I run the docker compose file  (dc -f docker-compose.yml up -d)
I see that all three containers started:
[+] Running 3/3
 ✔ Container docker-controller-1    Started                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s 
 ✔ Container docker-api-server-1    Started                                                                                                                                                                    0.8s 
 ✔ Container docker-model-worker-1  Started                                                                                                                                                                    3.3s 

but, when I run docker ps I only see the first two (not the model worker).
When I run the same code with a huggingface model, e.g. --model-path, "${FASTCHAT_WORKER_MODEL_PATH:-meta-llama/Meta-Llama-3.1-8B}" I don't have this issue.
Could you please advise how to run this code with my model ?

You don't seem to have actually included the code in your question; can you [edit] it to include a [mcve]?  Containers have isolated filesystems and can't normally see files directly on the host, so your Compose setup needs a volumes: block to inject host files into the container.
